# Declaration of \Interceptor::execute() must be compatible with \Detail::execute():

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4

I'm trying to display a simple page, but still getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Macademy\Blog\Controller\Post\Detail\Interceptor::execute() must be compatible with Macademy\Blog\Controller\Post\Detail::execute(): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page in /var/www/html/generated/code/Macademy/Blog/Controller/Post/Detail/Interceptor.php on line 19
```

**PHP** 7.4.30

**Magento** 2.4.5

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Macademy\Blog\Controller\Post;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Detail implements HttpGetActionInterface {
    private $pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    public function execute(): Page {
        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally since Magento 2.4.4 requires PHP 8.1

This code should work in Magento 2.4.5

Looks like you have incorrect generated cache and you just need to remove `generated/code/*` for developer mode or run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` for production.

I just checked this scenario and Magento generates correct `Interceptor`

```php
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function execute() : \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'execute');
        return $pluginInfo ? $this->___callPlugins('execute', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo) : parent::execute();
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much!
Just to clarify. Do I need to do this everytime I'm gonna do something specific, like creating a new page?

Comment: For development I suggest to use `development` mode and you need to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` every time when your changes is ready. When you have any unexpected behavior - make sense to flush everything. In development mode for more cases you enough to flush cache.